# Draw a white line across a transparent image in Python

Tags: python

I have transparent image which is semicircle, which I plot on a map. But when I plot on a map the image is completely transparent and thus I cannot see the semicircle. I need to draw a white  color boundary of transparent semicircle
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTYpO.png)

The area inside the dotted white line in transparent, i want to make that white line thick completely around the transparent part completing the semicircle from down to above.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('img2.png')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 0 and item[1] == 0 and item[2] == 0:
        newData.append((0, 0, 0, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("img3.png", "PNG")
```

Comment: What about showing your code? Telling us the library you use etc... [ask]

Comment: I havent started, I've just made an image transparent, ill add the code. I want to add border to transparent image